# How to list specific node/edge in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, traversal, networkx

Suppose one below tree-like structure in `networkx` graph:

```
n-----n1----n11
 |     |----n12
 |     |----n13
 |           |----n131 
 |----n2             | 
 |     |-----n21     X
 |     |-----n22     |
 |            |----n221 
 |----n3


      n4------n41
      n5
```

1. How to list all nodes with "subnode" and its depth,  here: n,n1,n13,n2,n22,n4
2. How to list all nodes without "subnode", here: n11,n12,n21,n41,n5
3. How to list orphan node, here: n5 and how to list "orphan" edge, not belongs to root n edge, here n4-n41,
4. How to list node with more than 2 "subnode", here n,n1
5. How to deal with if n131,n221 have an edge exists in nodes traversal, will infinity loop happen?

Thanks.

Comment: You should take a look at the networkX documentation of Graphs: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/classes.graph.html#networkx.Graph Most of your tasks can be solved with functionality from there and a bit of iteration.

Comment: @Michael Mauderer, is that so simple for nodes without attribute?

Comment: Attributes shouldn't make any difference for what you are doing.

Comment: You should give an example construction of the graph so we can help with each of these

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Graph construction:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> G = nx.DiGraph()
>>> G.add_edges_from([('n', 'n1'), ('n', 'n2'), ('n', 'n3')])
>>> G.add_edges_from([('n4', 'n41'), ('n1', 'n11'), ('n1', 'n12'), ('n1', 'n13')])
>>> G.add_edges_from([('n2', 'n21'), ('n2', 'n22')])
>>> G.add_edges_from([('n13', 'n131'), ('n22', 'n221')])
>>> G.add_edges_from([('n131', 'n221'), ('n221', 'n131')]
>>> G.add_node('n5')
```

1. Using the [out_degree](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_degree.html#networkx.DiGraph.out_degree) function to find all the nodes with children:

   ```
   >>> [k for k,v in G.out_degree().iteritems() if v > 0]
   ['n13', 'n', 'n131', 'n1', 'n22', 'n2', 'n221', 'n4']
   ```

   Note that n131 and n221 also show up here since they both have an edge to each other. You could filter these out if you want.
2. All nodes without children:

   ```
   >>> [k for k,v in G.out_degree().iteritems() if v == 0]
   ['n12', 'n11', 'n3', 'n41', 'n21', 'n5']
   ```
3. All orphan nodes, i.e. nodes with degree 0:

   ```
   >>> [k for k,v in G.degree().iteritems() if v == 0]
   ['n5']
   ```

   To get all orphan "edges", you can get the list of components of the graph, filter out the ones that don't contain `n` and then keep only the ones that have edges:

   ```
   >>> [G.edges(component) for component in nx.connected_components(G.to_undirected()) if len(G.edges(component)) > 0 and 'n' not in component]
   [[('n4', 'n41')]]
   ```
4. Nodes with more than 2 children:

   ```
   >>> [k for k,v in G.out_degree().iteritems() if v > 2]
   ['n', 'n1']
   ```
5. If you traverse the tree, you will not get an infinite loop. NetworkX has traversal algorithms that are robust to this.

Comment: thanks for this clear demonstration, but for 1 can you show a bit more to find out that n131 and n221 is the deepest node along their own path to n, if we take "n" as root? i cannot fig out a way  that `shortest_path(n, X)` may working in that case, should neighbor() also involved?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: n221 should not be the children of n131 if n is root, vise visa. so how to detect this kind of nodes and define them as "no-children"?

Comment: If you have edges between siblings, it's not a tree.

Comment: Yes, techinally it is not a "tree" any more, i don't know how to name it, but this edge can do exists, the question is how to detect them in this "tree-like" structure?

Comment: Do you just want to detect nodes that have two edges between them?

Comment: take n as the start point, the node n121 has a path to n which is n-n1-n13-n131, and n221 has a path to n which is n-n2-n22-n221, the two path following their own "hierarchy" like structure respectively. n131 should not be the sub node of n221 also n221 should not be the sub node of n131 as well. 
But the edge between n131 and n221 do exists which may lead to this, if i try to find if there is deeper neighbor node after n131 along the path n-n1-n13-n131, the node n221 will come to my list, i do not want to see that node.

Comment: (cont'd) So, what i want is to detected this kind of edge(can take any node as start point, in this sample, n is starting),is that possible?

Comment: Do you just want to find cycles then? I'm still a little unclear exactly what you want to do. Maybe start a new question?