# Networkx graph searches: dfs_successors vs. dfs_predecessors

Tags: python, graph, traversal, networkx

Consider the following graph structure (borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020020/how-to-list-specific-node-edge-in-networkx)):

```
G = networkx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('n', 'n1'), ('n', 'n2'), ('n', 'n3')])
G.add_edges_from([('n4', 'n41'), ('n1', 'n11'), ('n1', 'n12'), ('n1', 'n13')])
G.add_edges_from([('n2', 'n21'), ('n2', 'n22')])
G.add_edges_from([('n13', 'n131'), ('n22', 'n221')])
```

which yields:

```
n---->n1--->n11
 |     |--->n12
 |     |--->n13
 |           |--->n131 
 |--->n2              
 |     |---->n21     
 |     |---->n22     
 |            |--->n221 
 |--->n3
```

I can perform a depth-first search for successors starting at node `n` and get:

```
> dfs_successors(G, 'n')
{'n': ['n1', 'n2', 'n3'],
 'n1': ['n12', 'n13', 'n11'],
 'n13': ['n131'],
 'n131': ['n221'],
 'n2': ['n22', 'n21']}
```

However, when I do a depth-first search for predecessors at e.g. node `n221`, nothing happens:

```
> dfs_predecessors(G, 'n221')
{}
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
{'n221': ['n22', 'n2', 'n']}
```

What is going wrong here, and how can I get my expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dfs_predecessors() function only gives the immediate predecessor.
So if you say this (DFS of G from node 'n' and looking back one link from 'n22')

```
>>> print(networkx.dfs_predecessors(G, 'n')['n221'])
n22
```

you get part of what you want.

To get the path in the DFS tree from n221 back to the root:

```
>>> T = networkx.dfs_tree(G,'n')

>>> print(networkx.shortest_path(G.reverse(),'n221','n'))
['n221', 'n22', 'n2', 'n']
```

Comment: I would have liked dfs_predecessors() to behave like dfs_successors(), but it does not. Both of these functions are defined in terms of dfs_edges(), which only runs forward. Alas.

Comment: The shortest__path method for traversing from a leaf to a root works for trees, but as well for more complicated graphs. Imagine a DiGraph with multiple roots.

Comment: I just discovered that bfs_edges() has a `reverse=`  option traversing in the reverse direction. If dfs_edges() had the same option, it would be simple to to write a version of dfs_predecessors() that behave in the way that you expected.  Sounds like an opportunity for some open source work. Happy.