# Traversing level order for the graph in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to convert a `DiGraph` into n-ary tree and displaying the nodes in level order or BFS. My tree is similar to this, but much larger, for simplicity using this example:

```
G = networkx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([('n', 'n1'), ('n', 'n2'), ('n', 'n3')])
G.add_edges_from([('n4', 'n41'), ('n1', 'n11'), ('n1', 'n12'), ('n1', 'n13')])
G.add_edges_from([('n2', 'n21'), ('n2', 'n22')])
G.add_edges_from([('n13', 'n131'), ('n22', 'n221')])
```

Tree: borrowed the data from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866902/networkx-graph-searches-dfs-successors-vs-dfs-predecessors):

```
n---->n1--->n11
 |     |--->n12
 |     |--->n13
 |           |--->n131 
 |--->n2              
 |     |---->n21     
 |     |---->n22     
 |            |--->n221 
 |--->n3
```

I am using `networkx.DiGraph` for this purpose and created the graph successfully. Here is my code for creating a DiGraph:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
roots = set()
for l in raw.splitlines():
    if len(l):
        target, prereq = regex1.split(l)
        deps = tuple(regex2.split(prereq))
        print("Add node:") + target
        roots.add(target)
        G.add_node(target)
        for d in deps:
            if d:
                G.add_edge(target, d)
```

I am reading the all the data from a file with about 200 lines in the following format and trying to get a dependency tree. My graph is around 100 nodes with 600 edges.

```
AAA: BBB,CCC,DDD,
BBB:
DDD: EEE,FFF,GGG,KKK
GGG: AAA,BBB,III,LLL
....
...
..
.
```

After looking into the networkx docs online, now I can achieve the the level order output doing a topological sort on the dependency tree, with the below code.

```
order =  nx.topological_sort(G)
print "topological sort"
print order
```

output:

```
['n2', 'n3', 'n1', 'n21', 'n22', 'n11', 'n13', 'n12', 'n221', 'n131']
```

The order seems correct, but since I need to process the jobs in a batch (which saves time) and not sequentially, I want the output in level ordered output batches or using BFS. What is the best way to achieve this ?
ex: level[0:n], ex:

```
0. ['n'] 
1. ['n2', 'n3', 'n1',] 
2. ['n21', 'n22', 'n11',] 
3. ['n13', 'n12', 'n221', 'n131']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the bfs_edges() function to get a list of nodes in a breadth-first-search order.

```
In [1]: import networkx

In [2]: G = networkx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_edges_from([('n', 'n1'), ('n', 'n2'), ('n', 'n3')])

In [4]: G.add_edges_from([('n4', 'n41'), ('n1', 'n11'), ('n1', 'n12'), ('n1', 'n13')])

In [5]: G.add_edges_from([('n2', 'n21'), ('n2', 'n22')])

In [6]: G.add_edges_from([('n13', 'n131'), ('n22', 'n221')])

In [7]: list(networkx.bfs_edges(G,'n'))
Out[7]: 
[('n', 'n2'),
 ('n', 'n3'),
 ('n', 'n1'),
 ('n2', 'n21'),
 ('n2', 'n22'),
 ('n1', 'n11'),
 ('n1', 'n13'),
 ('n1', 'n12'),
 ('n22', 'n221'),
 ('n13', 'n131')]

In [8]: [t for (s,t) in networkx.bfs_edges(G,'n')]
Out[8]: ['n2', 'n3', 'n1', 'n21', 'n22', 'n11', 'n13', 'n12', 'n221', 'n131']

In [9]: networkx.single_source_shortest_path_length(G,'n')
Out[9]: 
{'n': 0,
 'n1': 1,
 'n11': 2,
 'n12': 2,
 'n13': 2,
 'n131': 3,
 'n2': 1,
 'n21': 2,
 'n22': 2,
 'n221': 3,
 'n3': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, my graph looks like this http://imgur.com/a/fnZh3 I am also unable to get the nodes plotted with names or large enough to view. For some reason, doing the same with your code with works, but on my graph returns an empty list `[]`. I have update some details on the questions, if it may help!

Comment: Also is there a way I could print this in level[0:n], ex: 1. ['n2', 'n3', 'n1',] 2. ['n21', 'n22', 'n11',]  3. ['n13', 'n12', 'n221', 'n131'] ?

Comment: thanks for the effort, I have updated the question with more information, your example was very close to what I am looking for. Could you re-look into my updated question. any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated the answer.  You can use `networkx.single_source_shortest_path_length` to get the distance from the root.

Comment: Not sure if that would solve my problem, it's the nodes and the level in the tree I require. Let me check anyways.

Comment: What I wrote gives "the nodes and the level in the tree",  e.g. node 'n131' is level 3.

Comment: Thanks for you time! I figured out why my data set does not behave the same in the above example! Its due to leaf nodes have edges to root node. Therefore, I need to figure out if there is a way to implement max spanning tree with networkx. Please check this question when you have a free moment! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540705/remove-edges-from-a-graph-using-networkx

Comment: what if I don't know the source node?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `bfs_layers` which is handy for processing all nodes at the same depth.

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_edges_from([("n", "n1"), ("n", "n2"), ("n", "n3")])
G.add_edges_from([("n4", "n41"), ("n1", "n11"), ("n1", "n12"), ("n1", "n13")])
G.add_edges_from([("n2", "n21"), ("n2", "n22")])
G.add_edges_from([("n13", "n131"), ("n22", "n221")])

for level in nx.bfs_layers(G, "n"):
    print(level)
```

Which outputs

```
['n']
['n1', 'n2', 'n3']
['n11', 'n12', 'n13', 'n21', 'n22']
['n131', 'n221']
```